# Почему память занимаемая приложением не освобождается при уничтожении объектов?

Tags: delphi, память

При запуске программы, в диспетчере задач Windows пишет, что она использует около 3 мегабайт памяти. При работе идёт подключении пользователей, создаются объекты, и используемая память растет.

Почему когда клиенты отключаются и объекты уничтожаются, размер используемой памяти не уменьшается?

Comment: Высокоуровневые языки программирования используют свой менеджер памяти, который "под капотом" вызывает низкоуровневые функции ОС. Дело в том, что функции ОС работают медленно, если нужно много раз выделять небольшие куски памяти. Менеджер памяти для таких случаев запрашивает в ОС память большими кусками. Возможно в вашем случае менеджер памяти в делфи считает нецелесообразным отдавать память обратно в ОС, и держит ее для следующих объектов.

Comment: @Zergatul даже если простой более суток, менеджер памяти в делфи может считает нецелесообразным отдавать память обратно в ОС

Comment: Я не знаю подробностей его работы, знал бы, оформил бы как ответ.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/66428/discussion-on-question-by-artgrek13------).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можете подключить FastMM и вызвать метод `LogMemoryManagerStateToFile('memstate.log');`. Он выведет что-то типа

```
FastMM State Capture:
---------------------

179K Allocated
1100K Overhead
14% Efficiency

Usage Detail:
 64016 bytes: Unknown x 326 (196 bytes avg.)
 17760 bytes: TStaticText x 24 (740 bytes avg.)
 13904 bytes: UnicodeString x 272 (51 bytes avg.)
 8880 bytes: TEdit x 12 (740 bytes avg.)
 5928 bytes: TFont x 114 (52 bytes avg.)
 5320 bytes: TTimerSpeedButton x 10 (532 bytes avg.)
 ...
```

Верхние строчки показывают сколько памяти используется, сколько выделено (про запас) и/или не используется из-за фрагментации, и общий процент используемой от выделенной.

Вызывая метд во время работы программы вы можете легко отследить, как используется память и как она выделяется. Иногда процент эффективности может быть 95+, а иногда и меньше 4.

*Я так понимаю, что если свободной памяти у ОС много, менеджер памяти приложения не сильно заботится об эффективности ее использования, в угоду скорости работы. То есть при создании небольшого объекта, он может заранее запросить у ОС большой блок и постепенно его использовать по мере надобности, а при уничтожении объектов - не отдавать его ОС, а держать про запас, и не дефрагментировать расположение других объектов в памяти.*

*Дефрагментировать/компактифицировать выделенную память вероятно можно вручную, но смысла в этом не будет.*

Comment: Я скачал FastMM4, прописал путь к FastMM4.pas, поместил соответствующие DLLки в system32 и sysWOW64. В файле dpr своего проекта первым прописал FastMM4 перед Vcl.Forms. Куда вставлять вызов LogMemoryManagerStateToFile?

Comment: Вроде разобрался, логи добавил в вопрос, подскажите куда в них смотреть?

Comment: @ArtGrek13 Задайте это отдельным вопросом, а отсюда уберите.

Comment: Создал новый вопрос...

Answer (score 1):

Потому что делфи делает alloc (VirtualAlloc) для своего Borland_Heap, а у же из него выделяет память вам, а освобождая память она попадает в Borland_Heap, но не освобождается. Поэтому если вы пользуетесь делфишным менеджером памяти - то всё работает верно.

У вас проблема - иногда при уничтожении обьекта некоторые "детки" могут не удалятся. У вас может быть проблема как с Heap-системным (если вы используете ActiveX то возможно кому-то Release не сделали частая проблема), так и с Heap самого Delphi. Пожалуй вот хорошая ссылка https://habrahabr.ru/post/202242/